# Classes in a DLL

Tags: c#, class, dll

I was using a DLL in C# and called a method which returned me a C# object of the DBConnection class. My question is, if the DLL don’t know which language it will be used on, how can it return an object of a C# class?

Comment: is this DLL a .net dll or a plain windows dll. How did you call its functions

Comment: It is a .NET/CLR object, not a C# object.

Comment: In the IL - which is what the dll (assembly) consists of - there´s no such thing as a language, at least not C# or VB. It´s just IL. Thus even your C#-code is translated to IL. So it doesn´t matter in which language you wrote your code, it gets transformed to IL. However the details are far too broad for a single answer here, which is why I´m voting to close this question as "too broad".

Comment: It is unclear if you are writing your DLL or using external. For example if you are developing C# DLL then you should make your C# class exposed to COM and then you can use it with C++

Comment: Any compiler that can generate code that runs in .NET generates IL.  An acronym for Intermediate Language.  That language has support for objects, the way they behave in IL is not fundamentally different from the way they behave in C#.  Specific to DBConnection, the provider for a database is often written in the C language.  Made usable to any .NET compatible language by a wrapper written in the C++/CLI language extension.  Sometimes by using pinvoke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all DLLs are created equal. Some are COM-specific. Some are not. Some are .Net IL assemblies. Some are not. This DLL is a .Net assembly. The class objects it provides for your are *not* strictly C# objects. They are *.Net* objects.

This works out for you because C# is itself built for .Net, and uses .Net objects. If you were using VB.Net, F#, IronPython, C++CLR, or other platform that uses .Net, you'd also be able to use the DLL. But C, Java, VBA etc would have a much harder time.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET assembly is a standard independent of language. 
If you write a code in c# it will generate the same "assembly" .NET than VB .NET or F#.

The DLL does not return a "C# Object". The DLL return a .NET object.